# What's the point of badges on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

The way I see it, meta is a general discussion about Stack Overflow and there's no point to the badge system... or is there?

Is the badge system here intended to spark good discussion? As far as I can tell, reputation is carried over to here from Stack Overflow but not gained/lost here. Badges are the opposite (individual to each site).

I'd have thought the badges on Stack Overflow itself would have been sufficient?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Jeff Atwood designed badges as a way to introduce users to various features of the site. It's entirely possible for a user to be a heavy user of Meta, yet only have rare participation on the main site. Given that, it seems to me that it would make sense to also implement badges on Meta in (nearly) the same way that they would work on SO proper. I'm sure that someone else could provide a smarter explanation to the reasoning behind this design decision than I, however, lol.

Comment: I think your explanation is pretty clear. I just don't **really** see the point in them here. On SO itself - absolutely as it seems to suffer from abuse (or could) but here it's more questions by users interested in making Stack Overflow a place to share knowledge as opposed to ***dis codez don't work, fix 'em***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally see badges on this site a really rough idea on how active a SO users is on the Meta site. Basically the badge system here displays a users helpfulness on the meta site (*of course it's just gives a really rough idea*).

Answer (score 5):

There's a few reasons for this. Spencer nailed one of them quite well - *if* you appreciate having them, they're awesome - and if you don't, you generally don't mind them. They don't cost anything but some scheduled tasks to run.

Meta Stack Overflow used to be its own site, *not* a per-site meta, so the need for them initially was the same need that they serve on any other main site. Some of it is for incentive for users to try different features, some of it is for users to set longer-term goals, and we also now unlock additional privileges based on badges that you've earned (the dupehammer being one).

To remain as consistent as possible (given that Meta Stack Exchange exists and is a parent site, not a child meta), and to make sure new abilities based on badges also apply to meta sites, it just makes sense to keep them. I'm extremely pleased with how the dupehammer has worked, and I'd like to find new things that participation badges can grant.

Comment: The per-meta sites have had badges long before Meta Stack Overflow split off, though.